# How to use `tqdm` in python to show progress when downloading data online?

Tags: python, tqdm

I can find some [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm#hooks-and-callbacks) explaining how to use `tqdm` package, but from which I can't figure out how to produce progress meter when downloading data online.

Below is an example code I copied from ResidentMario for downloading data

```
def download_file(url, filename):
    """
    Helper method handling downloading large files from `url` to `filename`. Returns a pointer to `filename`.
    """
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
    return filename


dat = download_file("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/h9gi-nx95/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD",
                    "NYPD Motor Vehicle Collisions.csv")
```

Could anyone show me how to use tqdm package here to show downloading progress?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

As of now i do something like that:

```
def download_file(url, filename):
    """
    Helper method handling downloading large files from `url` to `filename`. Returns a pointer to `filename`.
    """
    chunkSize = 1024
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pbar = tqdm( unit="B", total=int( r.headers['Content-Length'] ) )
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunkSize): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                pbar.update (len(chunk))
                f.write(chunk)
    return filename
```

Comment: Thanks @silmaril... Additionally adapted *unit_scale* and *unit_divisor* from Shenez Chen's answer, makes the output more readable. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

pbar.clear() and pbar.close()

Manually update the progress bar, useful for streams such as reading files.
https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#returns

```
def download_file(url, filename):
"""
Helper method handling downloading large files from `url` to `filename`. Returns a pointer to `filename`.
"""
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pbar = tqdm(unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024, total=int( r.headers['Content-Length'] ))
        pbar.clear()  #  clear 0% info
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                pbar.update(len(chunk))
                f.write(chunk)
        pbar.close()
    return filename
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to silmaril, but the below works and makes more sense to me.

```
def download_file(url, filename):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    filelength = int(r.headers['Content-Length'])

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pbar = tqdm(total=int(filelength/1024))
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:                   # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                pbar.update ()
                f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: so basically you do two http request for downloading a single file.
Not very efficient, even more so if the target URL goes through a dynamic processing.